# jquery updating div with HTML that contains script

Tags: jquery, dialog

We are dynamically updating parts of our web page as the user navigates to different areas (by updating divs). We have one section that contains a jquery dialog along with the script that creates the dialog. When we first build the page, all is fine. We then update the div with new content that contains a new dialog but when we display this dialog we get the old dialog that was there previously. I have tried destroying the dialog before loading the new content, and in that case the new dialog will not display. The dialog is open with a button click event. It appears that loading a div with a jquery dialog does not work. Are there some limitations with this? I am loading the new content with the jquery div.html(content). The new content is being loaded as I can see other changes.

Comment: After updating the content and destroying the dialog are you reinitialising the dialog on the new elements (whatever element you attached it to?). Eg. `$("#dialog").dialog('destroy'); $("div").html(content); $("#button").click(function() { $("#dialog").dialog("open"); });`

Comment: How did you called your dynamically loaded dialog, can you give some codes ?

Comment: That may be the question. We simply update a div with the new content. The new content is a combination of HTML and script. I don't know what would cause the dialog init code to be called. The dialog code is just a function like "$(function() {". I assume this normally gets called when the page loads, but it probably needs to be called when the div is updated? We have other jquery elements that work fine (like buttons, drop lists, text boxes), its only the dialog that is giving us a problem. Our code is huge, but I could probably put a test page together.

Comment: @rjhdakota Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ rather than a test page. Regarding reintialization, after your call to `.html()`, you'll need to rebind the click event to call `.dialog('open')`.

Comment: hmm, rebind the click event. That will be difficult since when we reload the div we are just loading a chunk of HTML, we have no idea what is actually there. Is there a way to cause the rebind to happen when you don't know what the contents of the HTML are? It could contain one dialog, or many dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to rebind the cilck event from the comments. Rebind the elements in the success options in the `$.ajax()` call.

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Unbind all dialogs first.
        $(".dialog").each(function() {
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
        });
    },
    url: "/Foo/GetSomeData",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        $("div").html(data);

        // Get all buttons and bind click to open dialog
        // You'll need to customize this logic depending on your markup.
        $(".button").each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                // Determine which dialogs need to be bound.
                $("#dialog_1").dialog("open");
                // etc
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to find all the dialogs without knowing the ID's of each one? After the div is updated, I do not know the ID's. Much of our code it dynamically generated so the ID's constantly change.

Comment: Without some example dialog markup it'll be hard to come up with a way to get the dialogs. If you could add some markup to your question it would be helpful. Ultimately though, you'll need to come up with a system where the markup that is generated on the server side allows for the client side code to find the dialog elements. This could be a numbering system for example.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but re-binding did not seem to work. What did work is that we changed the ID's of the dialogs when we updated the div with new content. The new buttons were bound ok to the dialog and everything works fine. However, this probably leaves a memory leak as the old dialogs are still in memory. I will have to figure out a way to destroy the old dialogs (similar to the code above) but do it only on the section of code that is in the div we are updating.